# SWIG Callback with Output Parameters

Tags: python, callback, swig

My goal is to be able to define a function in python which modifies one of its arguments, and then pass this as a callback function to a C++ driver. I've been trying to accomplish this with SWIG and its [director classes](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_directors). Consider the following minimal example:

CPP.h :

```
class MyOp {
public:
  virtual void SetVal(int& val) {val += 1;};
  virtual ~MyOp() {}
};
int Runner(MyOp *op);
```

CPP.cc:

```
#include "CPP.h"
int Runner(MyOp* op) {
  int val = 1;
  op->SetVal(val);
  return val;
}
```

CPP.i:

```
%module(directors="1") CPP
%{
#include "CPP.h"
%}
%feature("director") MyOp;
%include "CPP.h"
```

run.py:

```
import CPP
class PyOp(CPP.MyOp):
    def SetVal(self, val):
        val += 2
print(CPP.Runner(PyOp()))
```

Unfortunately, this code segfaults. The [director documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_nn38) makes a reference to using [swig typesmaps](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_nn53), in particular directorin, directorout, and directorargout, unfortunately there are no examples.

I tried a few things with no luck. For example:

```
%apply int &DIRECTORARGOUT { int &val };
```

But this gives me a warning at compile time:

```
CPP.i:7: Warning 453: Can't apply (int &DIRECTORARGOUT). No typemaps are defined.
```

and crashes at run time. Interestingly enough, using `DIRECTOROUT` has no compile time warning, but also crashes. If you print out the value of val inside the python function:

```
class PyOp(CPP.MyOp):
    def SetVal(self, val):
        print(val)
        val += 2
```

You can see that the type of val is `<Swig Object of type 'int *' at 0x1053f5de0>`. So I thought about using `cpointer.i` to fix it. But even trying to dereference val with `intp_value` causes a crash.

I suppose I could try to avoid this whole issue by just having the output values I want (often times more than 1) be a member of the class `MyOp`, but it seems like there should be a good way to do this, and I'd appreciate any help finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cpointer.i` solution worked for me.  You'd have to show a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to fix your crash.  I just changed the following files:

CPP.i:

```
%module(directors="1") CPP
%{
#include "CPP.h"
%}
%feature("director") MyOp;
%include "cpointer.i"
%pointer_functions(int, intp);
%include "CPP.h"
```

run.py:

```
import CPP
class PyOp(CPP.MyOp):
    def SetVal(self, val):
        i = CPP.intp_value(val)
        i += 2
        CPP.intp_assign(val,i)
print(CPP.Runner(PyOp()))
```

Output:

```
C:\>run
3
```

Comment: Thanks so much Mark. You're right that I should have included all of my code from trying to use cpointer, because I made the stupid mistake of writing `i = intp_value(val)`, not `i = CPP.intp_value(val)`. Still, if anyone reading this question could figure out how to use the `directorargout` approach, I'd appreciate it, as that would simplify the python callback code.